# Relationship n:3 Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I was wondering how to model a n:3 relationship on Hibernate. I have seen a lot of examples using annotations @ManyToMany, @OneToMany.. etc, but none of them n:x, x a natural number.
Could you provide me a simple example?? Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you provide some more details of the actual example? Are the three referenced objects in the same role, or do they have different roles? First case you probaply have to go with a ManyToMany, second case you could use three distince OneToMany relations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use validators. i think that your requirement can not be considered as database design issue, instead a validation issue. use validator instead. You can write your custom bean validator (JSR-303) which validates the count of the elements in lists:

```
public class MyListSizeValidator implements
        ConstraintValidator<MyListConstraintAnnotation, List<?> /* list of any type */ > {

    public void initialize(MyListConstraintAnnotation myannotation) {
        //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    public boolean isValid(List<?> mylist, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        return mylist.size() < 4;
    }
}

@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = MyListSizeValidator.class)
@Target({ METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyListConstraintAnnotation {
    String message() default "List is full!";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

usage would be like this:

```
class MyCronBean {
    @NotNull
    @MyListConstraintAnnotation
    private List<MyObject> list;
    /** setters and getters */
}
```

UPDATE: 
you can use for JSR-303 implementation "hibernate validator" in Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.2.GA</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Which dependencies do I need to import to get these annotation??

Comment: my post was updated with dependency. use hibernate validator.

Comment: Thanks, maybe to make it more flexible I am going to narrow this relationship on a higher level, and leave this one as n:m. Anyway is good to know about validator. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

If you do not talk about [Ternary associations](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/collections.html#collections-ternary) (m:n:1) then you need to use @ManyToMany.

Comment: Is there no possibility to narrow the relationship?? How could I model it? Thanks for answering

Comment: I am not talking about a ternary association. I need A * ---- 3 B, A, B are entities

Comment: Blanca Hdez: a n:3 relationship is just a m:n (done by @ManyToMany) with some additional logic. - You need to implement this addtionl logic by your self.